# Algorithm for maximizing the product of powers

Tags: algorithm

Given two arrays of integers, B and A, how can we rearrange their elements such that ∏ A[i]<sup>B[i]</sup> for all i is maximized?

Comment: How about actually attempting the problem before you ask for the answer?

Comment: Are all the elements nonnegative?

Comment: Set A[0] = 0. One iteration of bogosort. Piece of cake.

Comment: Wes, I guess I could have spent some more time adding information to my question (such as my own work).  But, I was more interested to see what other approaches and proofs people would come up with.  Furthermore, responding in such a presumptuous manner makes you come across as a jerk and fails to add any constructive information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the arrays contain non-negative numbers, you just sort both A and B in descending order. To see that this gives the maximum product, consider that once A and B are sorted in this order, you can try to swap two items of A, say A[i] and A[j] s.t. i

```
              B[j]      B[i]
          A[i]      A[j]
          ------------------
              B[i]      B[j]
          A[i]      A[j]
```

i.e. A[i]<sup>B[j]-B[i]</sup> A[j]<sup>B[i]-B[j]</sup>, which equals (A[i]/A[j])<sup>(B[j]-B[i])</sup> where the exponent is zero or negative because B[i] ≥ B[j]. By assumption A[i] ≥ A[j] so A[i]/A[j] ≥ 1. Therefore the ratio is 1 or less as the exponent is either 0 or negative. This shows that the new product is smaller in value than the old product. Note: this is just an illustration, not a formal proof because it considers only the swapping of two elements.

Comment: The usual way of proving optimality for this sort of thing is to show that any other configuration can be improved - so consider any case where A[i] > A[j] but B[i] < B[j], and I think you can (pretty much) show that you can improve the result by swapping one pair. Therefore no unsorted solution can be optimal so the optimum is the sorted configuration. BUT what happens if A[i] can be -ve? Is this allowed by the problem?

Comment: Thank you for the clear proof.  I had arrived at this answer, but was not sure how I could prove it

Answer (score 3):

Assuming non-negative, it seems like you should just sort them both in increasing or decreasing (but the same) order.

Since everything is multiplied, you'll end up with A[0] * A[0]* ... * A[0] * A[1] *.. * A[1] *... etc.

With B[0] number of A[0]'s and B[1] number of A[1]'s, therefore, if you assume A[0] is the largest number, you want the most of them, so you should have the largest value B in B[0], and then you want the second most in B[1], etc.

If you can have negative numbers in A but not B then this still gives you the largest absolute value but the sign could be negative.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming array has postive integers,

If you take the log of the product:

It becomes `Sum B[i]* log A[i]`

Now this can be maximized if both are arranged in ascending order, because of the rearrangement inequality, (see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) and log being an increasing function.

So, sort A in ascending, sort B in ascending and you are done.